# Selecting all data from one table where conditions are met in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have two tables:

Table enterprise:

- id > integer
- name > text
- created_on > date

Table contact:

- id > integer
- enterprise_id > integer (matching from table Prime)
- first_name > text
- last_name > text
- created_on > date

I want to select all contacts of enterprises, created after January 1, 2010. What I have so far is `` Select contact.* FROM `contact` WHERE created_date < 01012010 00:00:00 `` but I don't think this checks the enterprise table?

Comment: What do you mean checks the enterprise table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check the other table, too, you could use `JOIN` (`INNER JOIN` in this case).

The general format for that is this:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Or specifically for your question:

```
SELECT contact.*
FROM contact
INNER JOIN enterprise ON contact.enterprise_id = enterprise.id
WHERE contact.created_on > 01012010 00:00:00 
AND enterprise.created_on > 01012010 00:00:00
```

To actually check the other table you might also want to elaborate the `WHERE` statement. For further explanations and especially examples, you might want to visit w3schools.com; they got plenty of help for SQL.

Comment: Ah-hah! That makes sense. I had gotten a little closer before reading your message and now it confirms it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from contact join enterprise on enterprise.id = contact.enterprise_id 
and created_date < '01012010 00:00:00' and enterprise.created_on > '2010-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

left join with table contact works better here . just try this if you want to select all data from contacts.

```
SELECT contact.*
FROM contact
LEFT JOIN enterprise ON contact.enterprise_id = enterprise.id
WHERE contact.created_on > 01012010 00:00:00 
AND enterprise.created_on > 01012010 00:00:00
```